# Google apps script to allocate sequential IDs to files

Tags: google-apps-script

Prior to using Google Apps for Work, our internal document system had a mechanism whereby whenever a document was created, a unique serial number was allocated to it, the file renamed to have the number prefix, and then added to the system.

This was an in-house tool so we controlled a database which doled out numbers.

If possible, I'd still like the same mechanism within Google Apps, but I'm not sure of the best way to approach this.

So far, I've got a spreadsheet where each row is an allocated number - and it records the date & time, user email and reason for allocation.

I have a working script already, within one document, which opens that spreadsheet, finds the next number to be allocated, and adds a new row with the details, then renames the document to add the number prefix.

This works fine, but as far as I can see, I can only add scripts to Documents and Spreadsheets.  Really, I'd like this mechanism to work for any file in Google Drive.

I'm starting to read up on publishing a domain-wide add-on, and I think that's probably the way to go, but I'm wondering if there's any way I can let my domain users use the script within Google Drive (i.e. viewing folders, selecting files, etc.).

Ideally, I'd like the user to be able to select some files, right-click and see an extra menu item like 'Assign number'.

Is this possible?  I've looked at the Picker briefly, and wondering if that's the way to select files, but not sure how I'd integrate the script to allocate the number?

Any help or pointers gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way if you want users to initiate the action is to write a little Drive app (not addon or apps script).

users then right-click any drive file and get a context menu with "open with..." and pick your "allocate number" app which then does the work.

see https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk

Comment: Ah, this sounds like what I'm looking for. Do you have any links to tutorials, examples, etc.?

Comment: Thanks Zig, I'm probably missing something obvious, but I'm having trouble trying to find what I need - I've started here https://developers.google.com/drive/ but can't really find any good examples or tutorials.  A link or two to specific pages would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Thanks Zig.  I feel I'm going off topic now, but I'm still trying to get my head around what 'installing a drive app' actually means. It's just a website, isn't it?  Can I restrict my drive app to users in my organisation only - can I bypass the Chrome Web Store? Thank you...

Comment: those i think are covered in the docs. you cant bypass the chrome store but you might be able to install it automatically to an entire gapps org. yes in the end its just a website together with a manifest that tells drive what kind of files you can open.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your internal structure and exact requirements, it's difficult to give a really detailed answer, but one thing you might consider is using a [stand alone script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) (I.E. One not bound to a doc of any sort) to iterate through your drive folders using the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) and rename any folders not found to be numerically named to whatever the next number would be.

Alternatively, the [HTML service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) would allow you to build an interface for uploading files which then triggered the rename. The one catch is it would always have to go through the interface.

Comment: Thanks @HDCerberus. Ideally, I'd like a scenario where the user right-clicks on a file in Drive, and it runs a Drive App which simply allocates a number and renames the file. Can I bypass the Chrome Web Store and allow installation for only users in my organization?

Comment: When using the Chrome store, you have the option to leave your app as 'Unlisted' (Where it's not searchable on the store, only available with the direct link) or 'Private' (Only available to a group you own or manage).